# how to compare two varchar values with leading zeros in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar

I have to compare 2 columns in mysql which has varchar data type. But there are some data which has leading '0'  which is creating problem while comparing.

For ex: **I have to compare between '02653' and '2653' which are actually equal, but here my query fails and gives different result.**

Please suggest any idea what should be the right query for this.

I have tried to run like this 
**SELECT DISTINCT `table1`.`store_id` 
FROM `table2`
WHERE 
CONVERT('first_column' AS INTEGER) = CONVERT('second_column' AS INTEGER)**

Showing this error
** for the right syntax to use near AS INTEGER **

Comment: For further context, please provide an example of the query that is failing for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
WHERE CONVERT(column1 AS INTEGER) = CONVERT(column2 AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: While running this query SELECT DISTINCT `table1`.`store_id` 
FROM `table2`
WHERE 
CONVERT('first_column' AS INTEGER) = CONVERT('second_column' AS INTEGER)     "for the right syntax to use near 'AS INTEGER'"

Comment: Try without the '' :
CONVERT(first_column AS INTEGER) = CONVERT(second_column AS INTEGER).
I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

convert the varchar to integer and then compare